# Sending data from mac to ios

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos, networking

I wrote a simple cocoa application that updates some stuff. Now I would like to send this updated data to any ios device. What's the best way for me to do that? Is diving into low level stuff such as socket and `NSStream` and such my only option?

Answer (score 0):

`NSStream` is generally the way to go, with device discovery through `NSNetService`/`NSNetServiceBrowser` (Bonjour). But a library like [MYNetwork](https://github.com/fmedlin/MYNetwork) might be better suited if you’ve never dealt with `NSStream` before. I’d suggest you try out something like [MYNetwork](https://github.com/fmedlin/MYNetwork) to see if it does what you want before diving into `NSStream`/Bonjour.